# How to compare time (only hours) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, time

I write the following script to compare time:

```
var TC1WarningTime = new Date(2013, 6-1, 30, 4), 
TC1WarningTimeformat = [TC1WarningTime.getDate(),
           (TC1WarningTime.getMonth()+1),
           TC1WarningTime.getFullYear()].join('/')+
          ' ' +
          [TC1WarningTime.getHours().padLeft()]+'HKT';

var TC1ReportTime = new Date(2013, 6-1, 30, 3), 
    TC1ReportTimeformat = [TC1ReportTime.getDate(),
           (TC1ReportTime.getMonth()+1),
           TC1ReportTime.getFullYear()].join('/')+
          ' ' +
          [TC1ReportTime.getHours().padLeft()]+'HKT';

var TC1CurrentTime = "";
if (TC1WarningTime>TC1ReportTime) {
    TC1CurrentTime = TC1WarningTimeformat; }
else { TC1CurrentTime = TC1ReportTimeformat; }
```

In the above example, TC1WarningTime is 30/6/2013 04:00 and TC1ReportTime is 30/6/2013 03:00. So TC1WarningTime should be > TC1ReportTime, but why the result gives me TC1ReportTimeformat instead of TC1WarningTimeformat??

Comment: Can you explain a bit what this code is supposed to do?

Comment: When I run your code I get the 04:00 time at the end as expected. You're missing a function that's needed to run the code, so I used a stub version: `Number.prototype.padLeft = function() { return this; };`. The code printed `"30/6/2013 4HKT"`.

Comment: Actually I have the following code (copy from the Internet) which I did not mention above. `Number.prototype.padLeft = function(base,chr){ var len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length)+1; return len > 0? new Array(len).join(chr || '0')+this : this; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you should definitely do is simplify the code. Instead of the repeated formatting code, you can combine those blocks into a single function:

```
function formatDate( date ) {
    return [
        date.getDate(),
        date.getMonth() + 1,
        date.getFullYear()
    ].join('/') + ' ' +
    [ date.getHours().padLeft() ] + 'HKT';
}
```

Then we can define the test variables without any complication:

```
var
    dateWarn = new Date( 2013, 6-1, 30, 4 ),
    dateReport = new Date( 2013, 6-1, 30, 3 );
```

Then, to compare them and get the later date, you can compare the `Date` objects directly, as you're already doing:

```
var dateLatest = dateWarn > dateReport ? dateWarn : dateReport;
```

Or, another way to do it is to use `Math.max()` on them. This converts them to numbers and returns a number, so you need to convert it back to a `Date`:

```
var dateLatest = new Date( Math.max( dateWarn, dateReport ) );
```

Either way, you can then format the result with the `formatDate` function:

```
var formattedDate = formatDate( dateLatest );
```

Comment: I am working on google map api V3. I want to show the WarningTime in the infowindow if it is later than the ReportTime. Otherwise, the ReportTime is shown instead. But in the above example, even the WarningTime is later(larger), it still shows the ReportTime.

Comment: And I just now tried to set the WarningTime(dateWarn) as 31/12/2013 03:00... If the dateReport is 28,29 or 30/12/2013 02:00, the dateReport is still shown. But If I change the dateReport to 27/12/2013 02:00, now it finally shows dateWarn.

Comment: > and < are perfectly suitable operators for more than just numbers. They do indeed work with dates, as well as strings.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I get for second-guessing myself - the first version of the code I put in this answer used the > on the date objects themselves just like the original code.

Comment: @AndyE Thanks for your information. But why the problem occurs if my code is used?
Micheael: Thank you for the amendment. Now it works! I am a newbie to JavaScript, so I might write something stupid... (However, my TC1 prefix has its meaning, because when necessary, there may be TC2, TC3...)

Comment: If you have TC2, TC3, etc. what that tells me is that you should probably be combining those into some common functions as well. You don't want to have to repeat the same code over and over again. Instead, make common functions that do the same work for TC1, TC2, etc. The bottom line: any time you find yourself copying and pasting a block of code, there's almost certainly a better way to do it, and it's worth your while to stop right then and find out how you can avoid the copy and paste.

Comment: Yeah, I understand. But I had some problem in writing functions in the past few days, so I just repeat the code temporarily. I will modify the code later. :) Just to tell you that I have the need to keep the prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Compare using `getTime()`. Like this

```
var TC1CurrentTime = "";
    if (TC1WarningTime.getTime() >TC1ReportTime.getTime()) {
        TC1CurrentTime = TC1WarningTimeformat; }
    else { TC1CurrentTime = TC1ReportTimeformat; }
```

Comment: But can this compare the date as well? (e.g. 1/7/2013 00:00 is later than 30/6/2013 23:00, I want to show 1/7/2013 00:00)

Comment: @hkson: yes, the getTime() function converts date (and time) to the number of miliseconds since 01/01/1970 UTC time and compare. You could check it.

Comment: @hkson: actually, datetime is stored internally as number of miliseconds since 01/01/1970 00:00 UTC. (You could check also the Date.valueOf)